# file upload via javascript in a loop only displays Uploading once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script and it works great to upload the files via iframe ... im using it in a loop so theres many forms like this one ..but the `document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";` 
only works for the first one... any clue how to fix this ?

```
 <script language="Javascript">
    function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
        // Create the iframe...
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

        // Add to document...
        form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
        window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

        iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

        // Add event...
        var eventHandler = function () {

                if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
                else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

                // Message from server...
                if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                    content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.document) {
                    content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
                }

                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

                // Del the iframe...
                setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
            }

        if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
        if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

        // Set properties of form...
        form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
        form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

        // Submit the form...
        form.submit();

        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
    }
    </script>

    <!-- index.php could be any script server-side for receive uploads. -->
    <form>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" /></br>
      <input type="hidden" name="fid"  readonly value="<?php  echo $fid;?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="numerolinha"  readonly value="<?php  echo $loader;?>"> 
         <input type="hidden" name="contador"  readonly value="<?php  echo $id_postt1."linha_".$events[0];  ?>">
    <input type="button" value="upload"
            onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/wallet_upload.php','upload'); return false;" >
    <div id="upload"></div>
    </form></div>
```

Comment: How do you set div ids? Are you sure they're unique?

Comment: i an adapted script....thats must be the problem ..but i was unable to change that part of the script

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to use the `language` attribute on your `script` tags; in fact it has been [deprecated for a very long time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=827) (It had already been deprecated for some time back then and that video is from 2006!). A simple attribute-less `<script></script>` tag will work just fine. All browsers that have ever supported the `script` tag have always defaulted to JavaScript.

Comment: autocomplete does that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it ... i used `$g++;` and now my upload as a unik id . tks to u all

```
<input type="button" value="upload"
        onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/wallet_upload.php','upload<?php echo $g ?>'); return false;" >
<div id="upload<?php echo $g ?>"></div>
```